# How to achieve push notification badge in android for all devices

Tags: android, push-notification, badge

I want to display push notification badge in all devices like Samsung,Sony,Lg etc., I want to display notification badge like facebook native application. i did small research for that in my result Android relies on the Notification Center to give the user indication about incoming events. So technically,  if your app already does that, you don't have to do anything else.
but some devices have own framework badge receivers.

**In sony**

http://marcusforsberg.net/blog/android-notification-badge-app-icon-sony/

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setAction("com.sonyericsson.home.action.UPDATE_BADGE");
intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.ACTIVITY_NAME", "com.yourdomain.yourapp.MainActivity");
intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.SHOW_MESSAGE", true);
intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.MESSAGE", "99");
intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.PACKAGE_NAME", "com.yourdomain.yourapp");

sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**In Samsung**

https://github.com/shafty023/SamsungBadger

**Add the following permissions to your application's AndroidManifest.xml**

```
uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ" 
uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE"
```

**To badge your icon with "1"**

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
if (Badge.isBadgingSupported(context)) {
    Badge badge = new Badge();
    badge.mPackage = context.getPackageName();
    badge.mClass = getClass().getName();
    badge.mBadgeCount = 1;
    badge.save(context);
}
```

Is there any other framework badge receivers code is available?

Comment: Why copy iOS's UI? Try to invent something new, please.

Comment: @Raptor: yes,you are right but some users wants to release same UI like iOS. they told facebook native app have badges why our app can't do that.   sorry for my poor english.

Comment: does Facebook native app has badge for all Android devices & launchers?

Comment: no it doesn't but some devices have that facility.

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: @micky very few devices have like this facility. Samsung,LG have own sdk to access their notifications. so please don't copy the iOS .

Comment: @prasad, mickey - you can support every device by using update app icon, check below link:              https://derivedcode.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/showing-badge-or-count-in-android-app-icon/

Answer (score 3):

I also faced same problem but perfect solution for your question is below link:

https://derivedcode.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/showing-badge-or-count-in-android-app-icon/

Comment: The link is correct and seems exact solution... thanks @androiddeveloper2011

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this libriary [ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/).

Description from github:

> ShortcutBadger: The ShortcutBadger makes your Android App showing the
>   count of unread messages as a badge on your App shortcut!

Comment: Worked great on Huawei and Samsung, till todays crash: https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/issues/364

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
1) Add mavenCentral to your build script.

 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

2) Add dependencies for ShortcutBadger, it's available from maven now.

 dependencies {
        compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
    }

3) Add the codes below:

int badgeCount = 1;
ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, badgeCount); //for 1.1.4
ShortcutBadger.with(getApplicationContext()).count(badgeCount); //for 1.1.3

4) If you want to remove the badge
 ShortcutBadger.removeCount(context); //for 1.1.4
ShortcutBadger.with(getApplicationContext()).remove();  //for 1.1.3

 or

ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, 0); //for 1.1.4
ShortcutBadger.with(getApplicationContext()).count(0); //for 1.1.3
```